# access my jar file items in eclipse

Tags: java, jar

I have two jar files "jar1.jar" and "jar2.jar" in my classpath 
now there is a file test.xml in "jar1.jar" , which can be read from my program 
by this

```
                 x=reader.readXml("test.xml");
```

but if i try to access some file from "jar2.jar" my program is not reading it,

is there a way to tell program that you need to read from this jar file, because its only reading from jar1 but not jar2..

thanks

Comment: post your code for reading from jar

Comment: i am using some API, which is giving me a method for reading xml , TanzilReader reader = new TanzilReader();
Chapter[] x=reader.readXml("/test-uthmani.xml");

Comment: you need to look at this URL from Oracle , showing everything for reading from jarfile : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

make jar1 in your class path,

In any class in jar2, try this:

```
InputStream is=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path to xml/test.xml");  
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adjust import order for your jar files. Go to project->properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export and make the `jar2` up in the export order. I presume You have same file in both jar files.

If your file in `jar2` has different name so, you have to verify:

1. This jar file is in your class path
2. Your pointing to a correct XML file location.

After above checks, you can use following line of code to read file.

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("<valid path to xml>");
```

Comment: thanks ,  have different files in both jars, and i want to read both of them , so if i change the order may be i will no be able to read from jar1, is it so ?

Comment: thanks , i used your code , but its showing the same behavior , its working fine with my jar1 , but not for jar2 , cant locate jar 2 file, I also adjust the import order

Comment: If file locations is correct in jar2, there should no reason causing the issue. Are you able to access classes in jar2

Comment: Jar2 have only one manifest and 2 files ,nothing else , I have made this jar file myself

Comment: may be i haven't created a jar file correctly , can u guide me with that

Comment: Yes, Sure. How have you created that Jar file?